# Android KTX - FragmentManager missmatch

Tags: android, kotlin, fragmentmanager

The Android KTX is grat, but it's a pain to migrate an app

> ```
> Requires androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager 
>
> Found: android.app.fragmentManager
> ```

---

```
class ViewPagerAdapter (fragmentManager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {

...
```

Comment: import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager instead of android.app.fragmentManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `: Activity()` or `: AppCompatActivity` to `: FragmentAcitivty()`

And then `viewPager.adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)`

---

The answer is kinda hidden on the documentation of [FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager)

> Your activity must derive from FragmentActivity to use this. From such
>   an activity, you can acquire the FragmentManager by calling
>   FragmentActivity#getSupportFragmentManager.

---

I actually post the question just to answer it, because I don't want to anyone to wasting 30+ minutes of their life to find the solution.

Android KTX is still in growing stages, so it would be nice to make easier for everyone to migrate their apps

Answer (score 1):

when you are creating `Activity`, just extend with `AppCompatActivity`.

```
class YourActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

}
```

or you can use `FragmentAcitivty()` too.

[image]

and then you can use `supportFragmentManager`

Comment: hi @nícolas-schirmer check this answer , it will help you